# How to implement BaseValidator and IValidator in custom control - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have a custom control that inherits from WebControl and implements IValidator, but I also want to have a property for ValidationGroup.  From research, it appears I need to inherit from BaseValidator to do so.  Can anybody provide a successfull example from a ASP.Net custom control that implements both BaseValidator and IValidator?

Comment: doesn't BaseValidator imply IValidator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheriting from BaseValidator will give you all of that.

You might find the source for this control useful as a starting point:  http://www.codeplex.com/UsernameAvailability

Comment: What if inheriting is not an option? This is really bad move from MS. Why didn't they put the property in the interface?

Comment: There is the IValidator interface that defines the basic methods of a validator. BaseValidator just helps you play nice with the other validation controls.

Answer (score 2):

BaseValidator implements the IValidator interface.  Simply have your class derive from BaseValidator and override or implement the necessary methods to support your validation logic:

```
public class MyValidator : BaseValidator
{
   public override bool EvaluateIsValid()
   {
     ... your code here ...
   }
}
```